# Feasibility: create ad-hoc network if it doesn't already exist

Tags: arch-linux, wifi

I'm working on a headless device (i.e. user interaction is difficult) and I'd like to know if the following use case is feasible:

- the device attempts to connect to a pre-defined wireless network (e.g. via a script)
- if connection fails (for instance because it does not exist) it will set up an ad-hoc network with a predefined SSID/password, etc.

Any pointers how to achieve this would be helpful, but I'm mainly looking for confirmation of whether this is possible in the first place...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible. Please take a look at the [ad-hoc networking](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ad-hoc_networking)-page on the arch wiki. There you will find a step by step tutorial for this with `wpa_supplicant`.